# Update and use updated list at each iteration in scala

Tags: scala

I have a list, and in each iteration I am updating the list (Get another list because its "val") And I want to use that latest updated list in second iteration and so on...

How can I do this?

Comment: Use foldLeft or foldRight. An example / use case would help to illustrate this.

Comment: okey.. Thanks for help..

Comment: Actually I want to use entire list after iterating.. So how can it possible woth foldLeft>

Comment: In what way are you trying to modify the list on each iteration? Can you provide examples of a starting list and the list after the first iteration?

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion. For example:

```
def range(x: Int, acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  if (x < 0) acc
  else range(x - 1, x :: acc)
}
```

Here you use updated list in each iteration:

```
range(5, Nil)

res0: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: I want to update the value of existing list not any addition or deletion... Just update some value and use that entire list in next iteration.

Comment: so using this approach you can update list and pass it as parameter